# Java add matrix antidiagonal elements

Tags: java, for-loop, matrix

I want to add a NxN matrix antidiagonal elements using a for loop in a java program.

This code (2 conditions) does not work because it always says when the loop is executed sum2=0.

```
for (int i=0,j=t-1; i<t && j==0; i++, j--) { 
   sum2 = sum2 + aNumber[i][j];
}
```

Instead this one (one condition) works well.

```
for (int i=0, j=t-1; i<t ; i++, j--) {
   sum2 = sum2 + aNumber[i][j];
}
```

Why does not work the first code?

Comment: `=j=t-1 && j=0` - is this exactly the code you have?

Comment: No, sorry I copied it bad. It is i<t && j==0

Comment: to get sum of antidiagonal you need to values of cell .but you are only getting  `aNumber[i][0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example the loop ends as soon as `j != 0`, if `t > 1` this means that it will end immediately, making no iterations at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
int maxIndex = matrix.length - 1;
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= maxIndex; i++) {
    sum += matrix[i][maxIndex - i];
}
```

This relies on the fact that the sum of the indexes of each antidiagonal element is exactly equal to N.